# How to get current object(Item/Region) name for authorization?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

It's not possible in Oracle APEX 4.2 to get the current object name like item or region. but it is in Oracle APEX 5.0

I m on APEX 4.2, is there a wat to get item name (not value).

Thanks

Comment: You state in your question it is not possible in 4.2. And you ask if it's possible? It's not possible.

Comment: It s not possible with APEX pre built funtions.
I m looking if there is another way to manage this issue !